# Multigraph and adjacency list

Tags: performance, graph, big-o

I have a problem that can be represented as a multigraph.  To represent this graph internally, I’m thinking of a matrix.  I like the idea of a matrix because I want to count the number of edges for a vertex.  This would be O(n) time because all I would have to do is loop through the correct column so the time complexity would be linear to the amount of vertices in the graph, right?.  HOWEVER, I’m also thinking of the space complexity.  If this graph were to grow, there could be a lot of wasted space.  This leads me to using an adjacency list.  This may reduce my space complexity but sounds like my time complexity just increased.  How would I represent the time complexity if I wanted to determine the number of edges for a particular vertex?  I know the operation would first be to find the vertex so this operation would be O(n), but then I would also have to scan the list of edges which could also be O(n).  So does this mean my time complexity for this operation is O(n^2)?

EDIT:

I guess if I were to use a HASH table, the first operation would be O(1) so does that mean my operation to find number of edges for a vertex is O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

It will be O(|e|), |e| can be O(|v|**2) but you wanna use adjacency list because the matrix is sparse so |e|<<|v| so it's better to say O(|e|).

Comment: sorry I mean |e|<<|v|**2

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  So if I have a hash table, and each hash has an array of neighbors, wouldn't traversing the array at worst be O(n)?

Comment: Yes, I get confused because you don't say n was the numer of edges, I assume you say n for the number of nodes, but it has no sense. Sorry.